# Incrementally load a webpage: Where can I put: $("#LoadingImage").Hide();

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am not very experienced with JavaScript.  Please see the code below:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">

    function GetSQLTable() {
        //alert($("#<%=fieldGroupReferences.ClientID%>")[0].value)
        var str = $("#<%=fieldGroupReferences.ClientID%>")[0].value
        var res = str.split(",");
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            $("#LoadingImage").show();
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.id = "div" + i
            document.body.appendChild(div);

            //alert(res[i]);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default3.aspx/GetSQLTable",
                data: '{username: "' + $("#<%=fieldUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '", terminalname: "' + $("#<%=fieldTerminalName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '", terminalip: "' + $("#<%=fieldTerminalIP.ClientID%>")[0].value + '", mappingid: "' + res[i] + '", usergroup: "' + $("#<%=fieldUserGroup.ClientID%>")[0].value + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess(i,res.length),
                failure: function (response) {
                    //alert(response.d);
                    alert('there was an error loading the webpage')
                }
            });
        }
        function OnSuccess(i,totalrows) {
            return function (response) {
                if (response.d != "") {
                    document.getElementById('div' + i).innerHTML = document.getElementById('div' + i).innerHTML + '<br>' + '<br>' + response.d;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    window.onload = GetSQLTable
</script>
```

The code incrementally builds a webpage i.e. x number of HTML tables are obtained and displayed to the webpage as and when they become ready.  This works.

The problem is I don't know how to remove the LoadingImage once the webpage is complete i.e. `$("#LoadingImage").hide();`.  OnSuccess is called x number of times depending on how many tables are returned so I cannot put it in there.

Comment: You would need to know what the limit it

Comment: Why do you make an ajax call for each of your clients? Imagine if you have 500 clients.. I think you could set them all into a JSON and send it with only 1 ajax.

Comment: Use [.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to group the `.ajax` call into a single deferred that you can then attach a `.then` to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to count the number of successful onSuccess() calls, and hide your loading image when they are all complete:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">

    function GetSQLTable() {
        //alert($("#<%=fieldGroupReferences.ClientID%>")[0].value)
        var str = $("#<%=fieldGroupReferences.ClientID%>")[0].value
        var res = str.split(",");
        var numSucceeded = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            $("#LoadingImage").show();
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.id = "div" + i
            document.body.appendChild(div);

            //alert(res[i]);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default3.aspx/GetSQLTable",
                data: '{username: "' + $("#<%=fieldUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '", terminalname: "' + $("#<%=fieldTerminalName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '", terminalip: "' + $("#<%=fieldTerminalIP.ClientID%>")[0].value + '", mappingid: "' + res[i] + '", usergroup: "' + $("#<%=fieldUserGroup.ClientID%>")[0].value + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess(i,res.length),
                failure: function (response) {
                    //alert(response.d);
                    alert('there was an error loading the webpage')
                }
            });
        }
        function OnSuccess(i,totalrows) {
            return function (response) {
                if (response.d != "") {
                    document.getElementById('div' + i).innerHTML = document.getElementById('div' + i).innerHTML + '<br>' + '<br>' + response.d;
                    numSucceeded++;
                    if (numSucceeded === totalrows) {
                      $("#LoadingImage").hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    window.onload = GetSQLTable
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe a javascrpt array is zero based so please change that. The code to hide the loading image is reached (confirmed by a breakpoint) but the image is not hidden. Any ideas? +1.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.when` with an array of your ajax calls. Something like this (simplified to remove the irrelevant bits):

```
function GetSQLTable() {
    //...
    var calls = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        //..
        calls.push($.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //..
        }));
    }
    $.when(calls).then(function(d) {
        // all done!!!
    });
```

Comment: Thanks +1.  Will the webpage still load incrementally?

Comment: Yes - the `.ajax` calls will all fire as soon as you create them and will execute their own `success` or `done` handlers as they complete. The final `.then` (or `.done`) will only execute when *all* of the deferreds have been resolved (i.e. all your `.ajax` calls have completed).